# How can I write a real time stats system? in ajax and php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, polling, real-time

I trying to make a realtime stats bar.
And I think of using the Long Polling concept.

But when a request is send to php.
I need a way of testing if the stats are updated.

Now I can just make a loop with a database query, and test it.
But that just doesn't seem right to me :)

Is there a more inexpensive method of testing the database for updates?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on how intensive the query for determining whether stats are updated is. If it's a simple (and fast) query, then that would be the best option. If it's an expensive query, change how the stats are updated so you either set a datestamp or have a DB trigger do it for you. No matter what, you're going to need *some type* of query to check for updates.

And you can't "push" from server to client either, so no matter what you'll need ajax polling so the client initiates the check....